# Troubleshooting Cell Spacing in Bootstrap 5.3.1: Using 'g-2' without Desired Effect

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I am currently working on a project using Bootstrap version 5.3.1, and I am facing an issue while trying to create a gap between cells. Specifically, I have added the `'g-2'` class to achieve this, but as the attached image demonstrates, it does not seem to have the desired effect.
[image]

Here my code:

```
function Wallet() {
  return (
    <div className="container mt-4">
      <div className="row g-2">
        <div className="col border">
          <div className="row p-3 h-100">
            <h5 className="text-center">Lorem Ipsum</h5>
            <div className="col">
              <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h5>
            </div>
            <div className="col">
              <h5>Consectetur adipiscing elit</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col border">
          <div className="row p-3 h-100">
            <h5 className="text-center">Lorem Ipsum</h5>
            <ul>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
              <li>Consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row g-2">
        <div className="col border">
          <div className="row p-3 h-100">
            <h5 className="text-center">Lorem Ipsum</h5>
            <div className="col">
              <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h5>
            </div>
            <div className="col">
              <h5>Consectetur adipiscing elit</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col border">
          <div className="row p-3 h-100">
            <h5 className="text-center">Lorem Ipsum</h5>
            <ul>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
              <li>Consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Wallet;
```